# TypeError: Cannot read property '$$hashKey' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object return by http post in angular

```
var altest = {

//here I have an empty object prepared to be extend

  Detail: {}

init : function(passdata) {

  var self = this;

  var dataResult = self.getVacanshitDetail(passdata);   

  console.log(dataResult);

  self.Detail = dataResult;

  console.log(self.Detail );
  //return self.Detail .info;
},

  getVacanshitDetail: function(passdata) {
    var self = this;      
    $http.post(Constants.API.baseUrl).success( function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        angular.extend(self.Detail,response);
    });
  },
```

However, in the extend line, in the console log it says: **TypeError: Cannot read property '$$hashKey' of undefined**

```
//object response from http request 

Object {
    title:  'Frog',
    url:    '/img/picture.jpg',
    width:  300,
    height: 200
  };
```

Please help what I need to do to achieve what I want and avoid the error.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: can you console log self and see if detail is null or undefined? normally this error occures when object is in those states, and you declare an empty object which seems to be right thing to do as mentioned on other posts

Comment: If I console log the response in the `getVacanshitDetail` state, it returns an object. But now I need to extend it.

Comment: And if I console log the `self.Detail` in the `getVacanshitDetail` state, it is undefined.

Comment: Please help me how to correctly do this. I am still newbie in this area.

Comment: Just the same, `ReferenceError: Detail is not defined`

Comment: Yes, I do want to extend `altest.Detail`?

Comment: Please look at my edit code.

Comment: What I want actually is only to get the data in `  Detail: {} ` From `getVacanshitDetail`. Please direct me how.

Comment: can you add semi colon to the end of this Detail: {} not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: you are **redefining** `self` inside your `getVacanshitDetail` function;  after that declaration, it no longer points to the parent object, but to the child property `getVacanshitDetail`.  you should remove this line from inside the function.  Also as a side note, you should consider using `.then` instead of the deprecated `.success`.